# traverse an array in GUI Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, guice

I am doing a questionnaire with questions and written answers.
I need that when adding the answer, press the main button, tell me if it is correct or not and show me the other question of the array, until the array is finished. Here I upload the whole code.

```
mainbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    for(int i=0;i<question;i++) {
        if(answer.getText()==(option[i])) {
        message.setText("is correct");
        corrects++;
                }
    else {
    message.setText("incorrect");
       }
  
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you need an animation library. Swing doesn't on its own make animation nearly as easy as it can be. I believe there are projects on GitHub that can add this

Comment: So far, you haven't specified any problem, so I'm not sure what answer you're expecting. You might want to edit your question to make it clear what you're asking.

Comment: We need more information of what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I need that when answering a question and pressing the button, it shows me the other question from the array

Comment: That can not be done with just a piece of code , try to google it and come here if you are facing errors.

Comment: there I uploaded the entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you need to process the questions one at a time, not all at once inside the ActionListener.

One way to approach this is to keep track of the question outside of the action listener, in this example we use `int questionCounter = 0;` to keep track of the current question, then we can remove the `for` loop and process the questions one at a time. Here is a simple example of how it could work using your code, note how we reset the fields and add the next question every time the previous question is answered.

```
//Use a variable outside of the action listener to keep track of the current question:
int questionCounter = 0;

//Show first question in the text area:
area.setText(question[questionCounter]);

mainbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(answer.getText().equals(option[questionCounter])) {
        message.setText("The previous answer was correct");
        corrects++;
        //Update the total each time you get one correct
        correct_answers.setText("correct answers: "+corrects);
    }
    else {
        message.setText("The previous answer was incorrect");
    }
    
    //Increment for the next question    
    questionCounter++;

    //Check if there is another question, then show it
    if (questionCounter < question.length){
        answer.setText("");
        area.setText(question[questionCounter]);
    }
    //Show the overall results if there are no more answers to check
    else{
        area.setText("Quiz complete, you got " + corrects + " out of " + question.length + " correct.");
    }
};
```